# Proof for differentiation of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

How the differentiation of sin(x) is cos(x)?

I tried finding the proof online but couldn't. Can I get to knoe the proof?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You'll need to practice your search skills! There are already plenty of proofs on this site alone: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+derivative+of+sine+proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${df(x)\over dx} = lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} { f(x+\Delta x) - f(x) \over \Delta x)}$

${d\over dx}sin(x) = lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} { sin(x+\Delta x) - sin(x) \over \Delta x)}$

= $ lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} { sin(x)\cdot cos(\Delta x)+ cos(x)\cdot sin(\Delta x) - sin(x) \over \Delta x)}$

$cos(\Delta x) \rightarrow 1$ as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$

$ lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} { sin(x)\cdot 1 + cos(x)\cdot sin(\Delta x) - sin(x) \over \Delta x)}$

= $ lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} { sin(x)\cdot 1 - sin(x) + cos(x)\cdot sin(\Delta x) \over \Delta x)}$

= $ lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} { cos(x)\cdot sin(\Delta x) \over \Delta x)}$

${d\over dx}sin(x) = lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} cos(x)\cdot {sin(\Delta x)\over \Delta x}$

${sin(\Delta x)\over \Delta x } \rightarrow 1$ as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$

= ${d\over dx}sin(x) =  cos(x)\cdot 1 = cos(x)$

Hence proved

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: I thought these rules were made early and were defined and thought that their proof would rarely be available.

Comment: @Levis100 You must try to prove other ratios yourself in a similar way.